# How do I run the main script of a Python package directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I have an issue on a large set of scripts I've put into a package, and setup a test repo `package_test` to get things working, as shown below. I'm using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10, with VS Code as my IDE.

```
package_test/
-- package_test/
---- __init__.py
---- __main__.py
---- package_test.py
---- module_1.py
-- setup.py
```

I have gotten things to work so that I can run this as a module, using `python -m package_test` from the root of this directory. However, if I try to run the `package_test.py` module directly (such as having VS Code launch it, or to use the debugger), I get an error.

The problem appears to be with imports. Why can't I run the `package_test.py` script directly?

---

Here are the relevant files:

**__init__.py**

```py
from .module1 import *
```

**__main__.py**

```py
import package_test.package_test

def main():
    package_test.package_test.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**package_test.py**

```py
import package_test
from package_test.module1 import *

def main():
    package_test.module1.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**module1.py**

```py
import package_test
from .module1 import *

def textfx():
    print('Hello textfx!!')

def main():
    package_test.module1.textfx()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

The error when running directly is:

```sh
USER@PC MINGW64 /c/Code/python/package_test (master)
$ C:/apps/Python37/python.exe c:/Code/python/package_test/package_test/package_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Code/python/package_test/package_test/package_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package_test
  File "c:\Code\python\package_test\package_test\package_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from package_test.module1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_test.module1'; 'package_test' is not a package
```

But, when I run this as a module, the result is:

```sh
USER@PC MINGW64 /c/Code/python/package_test (master)
$ py -m package_test
Hello textfx!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the documentation of [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. [...]

Since you are running `package_test$ python package_test/package_test.py` the first place where Python will look for modules in your example is `package_test/package_test`. Here it finds the module `package_test.py` which you import via `import package_test`. Now this module is cached in `sys.modules`. When you do `from package_test.module1 import *` it fetches `package_test` from the module cache and reports back that this isn't a package and thus it can't perform the import.

You should rename that `package_test.py` script to something else. Why does it exist in the first place when all it does is importing from another module and `__main__` just imports from that script. Why can't you run `__main__.py` and have it import from `module1` directly?

You can place this code at the top of `package_test.py` and inspect the output:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

import package_test
print(sys.modules)
print(package_test)
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm still relatively new to Python and have been having trouble figuring out how to set up the package and still run the modules directly. So I'm partly guessing what to do. In this example the package_test.py could be eliminated like you suggest, but in my more complex real-life project it is calling other modules in sequence, and running other functions. I'll try some of this out - the attempt to double import is probably looks like the root cause.

Comment: @LightCC The main problem is that you have a module *within* your package that has the same name as the package and even attempts to import the package by that name (and as a result of that name conflict it will just import itself instead of the package). Hence renaming that module also solves your problem.

Comment: The main issue seems to be `sys.path[0]` being different depending on whether I run the script inside the package folder, or run the package from the package's parent directory (neither are on any path). The `__name__` and `__package__` attributes also change for the package_test.py script. One way to resolve this without a bunch of ugly hacks is simply to create an "entry" script in the package parent folder that runs `import package_test` then `package_test.package_test.main()`. The the entry.py script can be run directly (for debugging, etc.) and everything runs the same way.

Comment: @LightCC If you run `python -m ...` nothing will be put on the path, but if you do `python path/to/package_test.py` then `path/to` will end up in `sys.path[0]`. Putting the script outside of the package does work but then again what's the purpose of it? Plus in your current setup `__main__` imports from `package_test.py` so you'd have to change that as well (this you should do anyway i.m.o.). In general I see no reason why you would want a module inside a package with exactly the same name as the package; usually this content goes to `__main__.py`. Do you have any specific reasons for that?

Comment: It started the same name as the package when I was trying to get all this working. No specific reason.  That said, it does all seem to be working fine, even with the same names, just need a `run.py` or similar in the parent package that runs scripts inside the package as an entry point.

Answer (score 0):

### Two Options

Based on a_guest's answer and further investigation, there are two ways to resolve this as I understand it:

---

#### #1: Do not have a module name that matches a package name

- This is basically a_guest's answer
- i.e. if `package_test` is the package, do not have a `package_test.py`. Name it something like `run.py` or other functional verb instead of a noun.

This will allow run and debug directly on the script by VS Code, and probably other IDEs as well.

---

#### #2: Always launch from an script outside the package

Launch the program from a script outside of that package:

- create a run/launch script in the project root and always run from there.

  - this will allow run/debug by VS Code, by running the external script.
  - e.g. Create a `./run_package_test.py` script in the project root directory and run a function in `/package_test/package_test.py` from that script.
- launch using an installed script from `setuptools`, `Poetry`, or another package manager (i.e. through a function entry-point). This will work even if you are referencing the problematic module with the same name as the package, because it is installing a separate mini launch script that points to the main script and imports the package reference first.

  - This method, would allow running and debugging by VS Code, but you would have to run the installed script that is located in the virtual environment.
  - For example, if you use the following in the `pyproject.toml` file with `Poetry` package manager:

    ```
    [tool.poetry.scripts]
    run = "package_test.run_package:main"
    ```

    To create a script called `run` when the project is installed (i.e. through `poetry install`), it will create a script in the virtual environment simply called `run` (with a corresponding run.cmd for windows). If you create local virtual environments, this would be located at:

    - `./.venv/Scripts/run`

    You could open this file (it is a Python file, even though it doesn't have the *.py extension), and run or debug it with VS Code.

I believe #2 works because you are forced to import your `package_test.py` script as a part of the package from outside the package, and cannot directly import the module.

This means the package gets imported first (or the module gets imported as a nested symbol under the package anyway). This gives us access to the package in the sys.modules cache, rather than just the module.